# Making a program to arrange a list of numbers from descending order with no built-in sorting algorithms

Tags: python

I was told to do this as homework. So far I did the following:

```
a = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
b = a.split()
for c in range(len(b)):
    b[c] = int(b[c])

n=[]
big=b[0]

while b != []:
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if big < b[i]:
            big!=b[i]
    n=n+[big]
    b.remove(big)

print n
```

Here's an example:

> 459113

And the output is suppose to be:

> 954331

The challenge is not to use sorting algorithms, which is hard for me to do since I don't know how to get around it.

The basis of that program is from:

```
a = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
b = a.split() 
for c in range(len(b)):
  b[c] = int(b[c])

n=[]
small=b[0] while b != []:
    small=b[0]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if small > b[i]:
            small=b[i]
    n=n+[small]
    b.remove(small)

print n
```

Comment: Er... arranging numbers in order *is* a sorting algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean "not to use sorting algorithms"? By definition any algorithm that places things in sorted order is a sorting algorithm.

Comment: I mean that I can't use built-in sorting algorithms in python.

Comment: which [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) are you trying to implement?

Comment: Shouldn't the input and output contain the same digits?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
a = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
b = map(int, a)
n=[]
while b:
    smallest = min(b)
    n.append(smallest)
    b.remove(smallest)
print
print ''.join(map(str, n))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ewsn4)

It's the same algorithm as your existing code, but I've fixed a number of errors. Note that this is not an efficient algorithm. It runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. Using the builtin `sorted` function you could achieve O(n log(n)) time, and with a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) you could even reach O(n) time.

Note that this sorts in *ascending* order, not descending order. Since this is homework I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out what one thing you need to change to fix this.

Here are some other notes about the changes I made to your program:

- Don't call split on your input. That splits on whitespace, which is probably not what you want since your example input doesn't contain any whitespace.
- I used `map` instead of a `for` loop to convert all elements in a sequence.
- I used `min` to find the smallest value instead of iterating over the sequence.

Comment: I tried it. Looks good since I'm familiar with some of the coding here. Also figured out what to change to make it descending. I got a question though... is it possible to get output in brackets?

Comment: @MarkSoo: What do you mean? Like this? `print ','.join('(' + x + ')' for x in n)`

Comment: Well just the output in brackets like this: [654311]. PS: I'm not sure where I can input that...

Comment: @MarkSoo: `print '[' + ''.join(map(str, n)) + ']'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to sort a list but here is another example :)
Im even able to do it without sorting them.

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading
import time

def sleeper(x, queue):
    time.sleep(x)
    queue.put(x)

a = [3,2,1,4,3,2,5]
longest = max(a)
threads = {}
queue = Queue()
for num in a:
    threads[num] = threading.Thread(target=sleeper, args=(num, queue))
    threads[num].start()
threads.get(longest).join()

while not queue.empty():
    print queue.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python you can try the following code :

`def Descending_Order(num):
    return int("".join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))`